# Prove or Disprove: If every nontrivial subgroup of a group $G$ is cyclic, then $G$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> Prove or Disprove: If every nontrivial subgroup of a group $G$ is cyclic, then $G$ is cyclic.

This is a question from page $181$, Chapter $3.4$ Elements of Modern Algebra ($8^{th}$ Edition) by Linda Gilbert.

My intuition tells me that the given statement is false, however, I cannot seem to find a rigorous argument (or counterexample) to disprove the statement. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

I know that if a group $G$ is cyclic, then every subgroup is cyclic. This is not an if and only if statement - hence my intuition telling me the above mentioned statement is false.

Comment: What is the smallest nonabelian group?.. :-)

Comment: @PeterFranek -  $S_3$? :)

Comment: @PeterFranek - can you please help explain to me why this is a suitable counterexample? :).

Comment: @DJS What are its nontrivial subgroups?

Comment: Subgroups $H$ of $G$ such that $H \neq \{e \}$ and $H \neq G$.

Comment: @DJS There are just a few of them.. write them down and see.

Comment: Not what is a nontrivial subgroup, what are they in the particular case of $S_3$

Comment: @Omry - Oh! My bad :). I misread your comment :). Thank you! This pointed it out quite clearly :) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is easily settled even without an explicit counterexample. There exist non cyclic finite abelian groups, so a non cyclic finite abelian group of minimal cardinality provides the counterexample. Indeed its proper subgroups must be cyclic, by minimality.

Of course, the counterexample *can* be shown: the Klein group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3):

A more exotic infinite counterexample is any Prufer p-group.

Comment: For an even more exotic example, you can take a [Tarski monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group)